# How to fetch data analyzed in python to node.js and pass it to angular?

Tags: python, node.js, angular

I am new to angular and i want to display JSON data from python to angular with the help of node.js and I used child process to connect python and node.js but I dont know how to pass it to angular service

## node.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const app = express()
const port = 8000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  let dataToSend
  let largeDataSet = []
  // spawn new child process to call the python script
  const python = spawn('python', ['test.py'])

  // collect data from script
  python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('Pipe data from python script ...')
    //dataToSend =  data;
    largeDataSet.push(data)
  })

  // in close event we are sure that stream is from child process is closed
  python.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`)
    // send data to browser
    res.send(largeDataSet.join(''))
  })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you just have to send a Http GET request from your service.

I suggest that you should read and follow this [offical http client guide](https://angular.io/guide/http) to set it up correctly.

Here is a simple service snippet. This should be enough.

```
 @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class MyService {
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    
      getData(): Observable<any> {
        const url = '';
        return this.http.get(url);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much can you please tell me what url i need to include in that

Comment: Usually if you develop a angular application using 'ng serve' a development server on 127.0.0.1:4200 (localhost) gets created. Now you a have your node js server on port 8000. So if you make a http request from your develop angular application it won't work. What I do is setting up a proxy to my backend. https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server